# Docker mount a volume and populate it from container

Tags: docker

I'd like to mount a volume from a windows host to a linux container and have the content of the target folder in the linux container populate the folder in the windows host.

Example:
- host folder: c:\Users\abc\myfolder
- container folder: /data/mydata
The container is built from an image that creates data inside /data/mydata

If I do docker run -v c:\Users\abc\myfolder:/data/mydata image, then c:\Users\abc\myfolder content will override whatever was on /data/mydata inside the container. I would like to achieve the opposite (put the content of /data/mydata from the container in c:\Users\abc\myfolder)

Creating a shared folder and then logging inside the container and copying the content of /data/mydata to the shared folder would expose the content of /data/mydata to the windows host, but it involves a manual copy and is not very efficient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature to control read and write permissions

You can specify that a volume should be read-only by appending `:ro` to the `-v` switch:

```
docker run -v /path/in/host:/path/in/container:ro my_image_name
```

But just works in container folder and by default (with any chance to modify) is **read-write on the host**

## Sync

Maybe you could:

- create a folder called /folders/left (c:\Users\abc\myfolder in your case)
- create a folder called /folders/right
- create a container to populate the /folders/right

```
docker run -v /folders/right:/path/in/container my_image_name
```

- ensure **/folders/right** is empty before container startup in order to not override the internal container folder
- with this you will have /folders/left (host folder) and /folders/right (changes made by container)
- finally try to sync left to right or another configurations with some tool

  - linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203854/188975